# How to use Controller and Model in slim php framework with example

Tags: php, slim

I have just got Slim PHP Framework with composer. Can anyone suggest me how to use Controller and Model in slim framework. And Where to put controllers and model in slim framework.Actually I want to use slim framework only for API. And I want to use controller for it. I have read its document but I am not able to find regarding controller and models.

Comment: Do you mean how the different components fit in a project structure? Or a code example?

Comment: No I did not mean that. I do not know at all about slim framework. I know Laravel, CodeIgniter etc. So I want to know basic routing and controller in it. Just give me simple code of Controller, just give me very simple code of Model. ANd also give me controller and model's file path.

Comment: There are plenty of examples online, just search [slim framework mvc].

Comment: Actually Rob Allen has just provided me a link https://github.com/akrabat/slim-bookshelf for learning basics. So I am now trying it.

Answer (score 3):

Slim doesn't enforce any particular layout for your application.

I tend to like to separate out PHP source from HTML templates, so I use this pattern (taken from [slim-bookshelf](https://github.com/akrabat/slim-bookshelf)):

```
app/
├── src
│   ├── Bookshelf
│   │   ├── Author.php
│   │   ├── AuthorController.php
│   │   ├── Book.php
│   │   ├── BookController.php
│   │   └── TwigExtension.php
│   ├── dependencies.php
│   ├── middleware.php
│   └── routes.php
├── templates
│   ├── bookshelf
│   │   ├── author
│   │   │   ├── books.twig
│   │   │   ├── edit.twig
│   │   │   └── list.twig
│   │   └── book
│   │       └── list.twig
│   └── layout.twig
└── settings.php
```

However, my APIs do not have templates, so I move everything up a level. This example comes from [slim-bookshelf-api](https://github.com/akrabat/slim-bookshelf-api/tree/master/api) and uses a separate class for each route's action rather than a controller class:

```
src
├── App
│   └── Action
│       ├── HomeAction.php
│       └── PingAction.php
├── Bookshelf
│   ├── Action
│   │   ├── CreateAuthorAction.php
│   │   ├── DeleteAuthorAction.php
│   │   ├── EditAuthorAction.php
│   │   ├── GetAuthorAction.php
│   │   └── ListAuthorsAction.php
│   ├── Author.php
│   ├── AuthorMapper.php
│   └── AuthorTransformer.php
├── dependencies.php
├── middleware.php
├── routes.php
└── settings.php
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks for giving me. Actually I was looking for such example. Ok let me try it.Thanks again.

Comment: I reviewed your code and  I tried to run composer install command from my Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal It gave me vendor directory. I created a Controller in app/src/Students/StudentController.php. So and I added $app->get('/students', 'Students\StudentController:listStudents')->setName('list-student'); in app/src/routes.php so I got an error  Callable Students\StudentController does not exist. So What I should I do please suggest me. I am running my project in NGNIX server and I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Learn composer. Specifically, look in composer.json and add your `Students` namespace to the `autoload` section and then run `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Bookshelf\\": "app/src/Bookshelf",
            "Students\\": "app/src/Students"
        }
    },  It is my composer.json code. I run composer dumpautoload command from my terminal.It was successful then I tried to run my student url It gave me error. Here is my error description:------  Argument 1 passed to Students\StudentController::__construct() must be an instance of Slim\Views\Twig, instance of Slim\Container given, called in /var/www/html/local.slim.com/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line 64